# Not able to create react app using npx create-react-app my-app

Tags: reactjs

[Not able to create react app using npx create-react-app my-app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmhYc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your terminal and/or the command as admin? Doing a rudimentary Google search gives a lot of results claiming it has something to do with antivirus software.

Comment: I've tried every sort of thing Running as administrator and turning off the antivirus but still i am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I myself solved this problem,The above screenshot contains the error of log in the cache and in that error we need to make it global for that we need to use the following command.

npm config set cache "C:\Users\Nvsatya\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global

by this command the error got solved and now the npx create-react-app my-app is working.

Thankyou